# Spring Security using OAM (Oracle Access Manager) SSO (Single Sign-On)

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on

I am new to Spring world and with the help of lots of information available online, I have pretty much developed Spring MVC Application I am working on currently.
Last piece I have to implement is to integrate OAM SSO in my application to use as authentication.
I searched a lot on web but couldn't find single example of implementing third party Authentication provider.

I finally realized that I have to use PreAuthentication but I am not sure how I would implement it.

I am unable to share my code because any thing I tried until now is not working and I feel that I haven't got right path yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

To give you brief idea about OAM, OAM authenticates user ID and Passwords and sends you authenticated requests with a cookied, OBSSOCookie. Using this cookies, you need to contact OAM and get User ID and password and also User Roles (Authorities). Any request coming to your application is already authenticated so you do not need to authenticate again. all you need to do is, using this cookie, need to retrieve user Authorities.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring MVC, you could use the [spring-webmvc-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) security library, instead of Spring Security. Use a [`CookieClient`](http://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/http.html) to deal with the OBSSOCookie and create your own [`Authenticator`](http://www.pac4j.org/docs/authenticators.html) to check this cookie against OAM.